# Uncaught type error $().chatbox is not a valid function in asp.net Masterpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am developing a chatting application using Signalr in asp.net . On that I am using javascript signalr client to connect to Chathub server .

I am facing an issue as Uncaught type error $().chatbox is not a valid function

```
$('#' + ctrId).chatbox({
        id: ctrId,
        title: chatTitle,
        user: userName,
        offset: getNextOffset(),
        width: 200,
        messageSent: function (id, user, msg) {
            chatHub.server.sendPrivateMessage(userId, msg);
            TypingFlag = true;
        },
        boxClosed: function (removeid) {
            $('#' + removeid).remove();
            var idx = showList.indexOf(removeid);
            if (idx != -1) {
                showList.splice(idx, 1);
                diff = config.width + config.gap;
                for (var i = idx; i < showList.length; i++) {
                    offset = $("#" + showList[i]).chatbox("option", "offset");
                    $("#" + showList[i]).chatbox("option", "offset", offset - diff);
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

FYI

Its working without using MasterPage . This problem only arise when using inside a masterpage . Declared a WebUserControl and registered that using Register keyword in MasterPage .

This is my designer page of WebUserControl

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ctlChatBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="ctlChatBox" %>
<div id="chat_widnow">
    <div id="chat_title_bar"> <span class="col-sm-9 text-primary"><strong>Online Users</strong></span>
        <div id="chat_min_button"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div id="chat_box" style="display: none;overflow-y:auto;">
    </div>
</div>


<div id="chat_div"></div>
<input id="hdId" type="hidden" />
<input id="hdUserName" type="hidden" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCurrentUserName" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCurrentUserID" runat="server" />
<script src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~") %>Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~") %>signalr/hubs"></script>
<link href="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~") %>styles/jquery.ui.chatbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~") %>scripts/jquery.ui.chatbox.js"></script>
<script src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~") %>scripts/chatboxManager.js"></script>
```

Comment: Make sure you are not including 2 different versions of `jQuery` on the same page. Also, make sure that jQuery is using the `$` variable, and its not another javascript framework.

Comment: thankyou @palash . I found one of the version of jquery is giving the ambiguity . since i removed its worked like a charm .